# Populate Mysql data as a ListView in android

Tags: php, android, mysql, listview, android-listview

I have started working on a client server application using wamp server and running in localhost. I have some values in the database(MySql). The android client needs to pull the data from the MySql db and display as a list to the user.

Can you please suggest how do I go about doing that! Or can you suggest a good tutorial based on this concept.

Comment: Can you please suggest what you've done and what isn't working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Something similar to this. Request the site with the needed info. And then receive the info back. Once you get your data you can decide how you want to manipulate it for your listview

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/mydb.php?a=send_some_info");
InputSource a = new InputSource(url.openStream()); //get some info
```

I don't think this is the best way to do it. But ask a sloppy question and get a sloppy answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try sending a HTTP request to your server with the query. In the server, the corresponding php file will retrieve the data from database and form a xml or json response with the data and send it to client. In the client you can parse the xml or json response and get the required data.